# How to undo thumbnail regenration

Tags: post-thumbnails

I recently used the regenerate thumbnail plugin in an attempt to fix cropped thumbnails. However, the regeneration ended up cropping all other thumbnails instead of fixing the few cropped ones. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnail generation cannot be undone. You would have to define the correct image sizes and crop you want and proceed with regenerating the thumbnails again